# PHP check file exists without knowing the extension

Tags: php, file-extension, file-exists

I need to check if a file exists but I don't know the extension.

IE I would like to do:

```
if(file_exists('./uploads/filename')):
 // do something
endif;
```

Of course that wont work as it has no extension.  the extension will be either  jpg, jpeg, png, gif

Any ideas of a way of doing this without doing a loop ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You would have to do a [`glob():`](http://www.php.net/glob)

```
$result = glob ("./uploads/filename.*");
```

and see whether `$result` contains anything.

Comment: `glob` can also be used with a bash-like brace expansion: `glob("./uploads/filename.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)`.

Comment: Any way of also retrieving the file if it has no extension?

Answer (score 9):

I've got the same need, and tried to use glob but this function seems to not be portable :

See notes from http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php :

> Note: This function isn't available on some systems (e.g. old Sun OS).
>
> Note: The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.

It also more slower than opendir, take a look at : [Which is faster: glob() or opendir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763290/which-is-faster-glob-or-opendir)

So I've made a snippet function that does the same thing :

```
function resolve($name) {
    // reads informations over the path
    $info = pathinfo($name);
    if (!empty($info['extension'])) {
        // if the file already contains an extension returns it
        return $name;
    }
    $filename = $info['filename'];
    $len = strlen($filename);
    // open the folder
    $dh = opendir($info['dirname']);
    if (!$dh) {
        return false;
    }
    // scan each file in the folder
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if (strncmp($file, $filename, $len) === 0) {
            if (strlen($name) > $len) {
                // if name contains a directory part
                $name = substr($name, 0, strlen($name) - $len) . $file;
            } else {
                // if the name is at the path root
                $name = $file;
            }
            closedir($dh);
            return $name;
        }
    }
    // file not found
    closedir($dh);
    return false;
}
```

Usage :

```
$file = resolve('/var/www/my-website/index');
echo $file; // will output /var/www/my-website/index.html (for example)
```

Hope that could helps someone,
Ioan