# PHP if statement with multiple file extensions?

Tags: php, html

```
if(!file_exists("dynamic/content_".$get.".html"))
```

This exists in a php file.  I need to modify this line of code to also encompass being able to navigate to dynamic/content_whatever.php, not just .html.

What is the best way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (file_exists("dynamic/content_".$get.".html")) {
    include "dynamic/content_".$get.".html";
} elseif (file_exists("dynamic/content_".$get.".php")) {
    include "dynamic/content_".$get.".php";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `glob()`'s awesome brace abilities:

```
if (count(glob("dynamic/content_$get.{php,html,txt,htm}", GLOB_BRACE)) == 0)
  ...
```

Hat tip to [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303691/php-check-file-exists-without-knowing-the-extension/3303718#3303718)

May be a bit slower than using `file_exists()`, as that function is very fast and additionally uses the [stat cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), and as far as I know, glob() does not.