# PHP - Check if file exists without knowing the extension

Tags: php, file-extension, glob, file-exists

I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303691/php-check-file-exists-without-knowing-the-extension), but it didn't work for me.

What I need to do is to check whether a file exists, in PHP, without knowing the extension.
I use this code:

```
<?php 
if (count(glob("/database/".$_REQUEST['thetitle'].".*")) == 0) {
echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false';
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Maybe it's relevant saying that the script is located in

```
[root]/functions/validatefilename.php
```

and the database in

```
[root]/database/
```

But it always returns false, no matter what the filename (`$_REQUEST['thetitle']`) is.

Comment: I doubt your file is at `/database/...`. That's the *root of the disk!*

Comment: Right, I forgot. In HTML, `/database/` would be a folder at the root of my domain. How would you do that in PHP then?

Comment: *URLs* in HTML are relative to the current/root *URL*, *local file paths* are relative to where the files are on disk/the disk root. PHP doesn't really care about URLs. URLs have nothing to do with local file paths and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
count(glob("./database/".$_REQUEST['thetitle'].".*"))
```

Comment: count(glob("../database/".$_REQUEST['thetitle'].".*"))

Comment: and are you sure that you have right permissions on database folder? [http://www.php.net/glob](http://www.php.net/glob)

Comment: It worked, thanks to maybe the permissions. But I also used `if (glob("../database/".$_REQUEST['thetitle'].".*") == "") {`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it works fine except that you should be specifying the full path:

```
if (count(glob( "/path/to/" . "database/" .$_REQUEST['thetitle']. ".*")) == 0) {
```

Comment: As my edited question now illustrates, /database/ is directly after the root, like website.com/database/

Comment: you still may need to explicitly map out the entire path

Comment: I tried `$thevar = glob("http://www.daltonempire.nl/database/Hello.*");
echo '"';
print_r($thevar);
echo '"';` and I put a file named "Hello.png" there, but it would still echo ""