# check file exist with regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have image uploaded on the server with the id of customer. But I don't want to upload multiple format of files twice (e.g. there should be only one image for customer id=1 that is 1.jpg OR 1.png)

How can I check globally while updating image whether that file is already there or not?

can I check file exist without extension of file?

I am using this command to check file.

```
file_exists('./media/customer-id/'.$cus_id);
```

Comment: Check the [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303691/php-check-file-exists-without-knowing-the-extension#answer-3303718) from the link I posted. You'll need to use `glob()`. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303691/php-check-file-exists-without-knowing-the-extension#comment-3422841) by _@Gumbo_ answers your question exactly. Make sure you search the site to avoid posting a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to run a `ls` like command and receive an array of the directories contents.  Then loop through the files and see if anything matches the customer ID.

```
$exists = false;
foreach(scandir('./media/customer-id') as $file) {
    if(preg_match('/^' . $customer_id . '\.$/', $file)) {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) for this and count the result.

```
function patternExists($pattern) {
    return count(glob($pattern)) > 0;
}
```

and use like this

```
if (patternExists("./media/customer-id/".$cus_id."*")) {
    // bad!
}
```

Comment: Note that `glob()` is somewhat of a quasi-regex. The `?` matches 1 of any character except a `/` and `*` matches 0 or more of any character except a `/`. +1 for a simple solution, though.

Comment: @Sam thx, I've renamed it to use PHP's formulation

Comment: @kingkero: how to see that image in browser without knowing it's extension.