# What is better than PHP Glob?

Tags: php

Is there a faster way to display a list of files by reading the directory than glob?  This works great for a few files but is very slow to display when there is alot of files in a directory?

```
<ul>
        <?php
            foreach (glob("directory/sub-directory/*.pdf") as $filename) {
            $shortname = basename($filename);
            echo "<LI><span class=file><a href=http://www.mysite.com/directory/sub-directory/viewer.php?doc=$shortname>$shortname</a></span></li>\n";
            }
        ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you think this code is slow? Are you sure it's not a browser that renders it not fast? How do you measure it?

Comment: How many files do you consider "a lot"?

Comment: The answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2763321/795876

Comment: Perfect...GLOB_NOSORT seemed to speed glob up much faster.

Answer (score 0):

opendir() is a little bit faster I guess.
How many files do you consider a lot? 
You might want to think about fetching only chunks of the files in the directory, loading the next chunk whenever the user scrolls to the bottom or the like.