# php script for generating links to folders

Tags: php

Need help for a php script / page for generating links to folders.
Have a homepage with photos that I upload using Lightroom – each album in a separate folder.

The structure is:

```
mysite.com  
  |--images  
    |--folder1  
    |--folder2  
    |--folder3  
    .  
    .
```

So I would like to end up with a dynamic index.php file that generates links to all the subfolders of “images” instead of the static index.html file I got in the root of mysite.com:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="mysite.com/images/folder1" target="_blank">folder1</a>
    <a href="mysite.com/images/folder2" target="_blank">folder2</a>
    <a href="mysite.com/images/folder3" target="_blank">folder3</a>
    .
    .
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$dir = "mysite.com/images/";
$dh = opendir($dir);
while ($f = readdir($dh)) {
  $fullpath = $dir."/".$f;
  if ($f{0} == "." || !is_dir($fullpath)) continue;
  echo "<a href=\"$fullpath\" target=\"_blank\">$f</a>\n";
}
closedir($dh);
```

When I need everything (i.e., `something/*`), I prefer `readdir()` over `glob()` because of [speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763290/which-is-faster-glob-or-opendir) and less memory consumption (reading a directory file by file, instead of getting the whole thing in an array).

If I'm not mistaken, `glob()` does omit `.*`files and has no need for the `$fullpath` variable, so if you're after speed, you might want to do some testing.

Comment: I gave the glob as an option since it's quick if you're only needing this for something quick and simple.

Comment: Thanx for the quick answers.
The last one worked “out of the box”. Will study the others more carefully tomorrow – need to hit the sack – its 04:40 in Denmark ;-)

Comment: @searsaw My comment was not aiming towards anyone in particular. As I said, I think `glob()` is something to be considered, although I'd expect `readdir()` to be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $files = scandir();
    $dirs = array(); // contains all your images folder
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
           $dirs[] = $file;
        }
    }
?>
```

use dirs array for dynamically generating links

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$contents = glob('mysite.com/images/*');
foreach ($contents as content) {
    $path = explode('/', $content);
    $folder = array_pop($path);
    echo '<a href="' . $content . '" target="_blank">' . $folder . '</a>';
}
```

Or also this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('mysite.com/images/') {
    while (false !== ($content = readdir($handle))) {
        echo echo '<a href="mysite.com/images/' . $content . '" target="_blank">' . $content . '</a>';
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```